# Sample two pandas dataframes the same way

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing a machine learning computations having two dataframes - one for factors and other one for target values. I have to split both into training and testing parts. It seems to me that I've found the way but I'm looking for more elegant solution. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

df_source = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,2),index = range(0,10,2), columns=list('AB'))
df_target = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,2),index = range(0,10,2), columns=list('CD'))

rows = np.asarray(random.sample(range(0, len(df_source)), 2))

df_source_train = df_source.iloc[rows]
df_source_test = df_source[~df_source.index.isin(df_source_train.index)]
df_target_train = df_target.iloc[rows]
df_target_test = df_target[~df_target.index.isin(df_target_train.index)]

print('rows')
print(rows)
print('source')
print(df_source)
print('source train')
print(df_source_train)
print('source_test')
print(df_source_test)
```

---- edited - solution by unutbu (midified) ---

```
np.random.seed(2013)
percentile = .6
rows = np.random.binomial(1, percentile, size=len(df_source)).astype(bool)

df_source_train = df_source[rows]
df_source_test = df_source[~rows]
df_target_train = df_target[rows]
df_target_test = df_target[~rows]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you make `rows` a boolean array of length `len(df)`, then you can get the `True` rows with `df[rows]` and get the `False` rows with `df[~rows]`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
np.random.seed(2013)

df_source = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randn(5, 2), index=range(0, 10, 2), columns=list('AB'))

rows = np.random.randint(2, size=len(df_source)).astype('bool')

df_source_train = df_source[rows]
df_source_test = df_source[~rows]

print(rows)
# [ True  True False  True False]

# if for some reason you need the index values of where `rows` is True
print(np.where(rows))  
# (array([0, 1, 3]),)

print(df_source)
#           A         B
# 0  0.279545  0.107474
# 2  0.651458 -1.516999
# 4 -1.320541  0.679631
# 6  0.833612  0.492572
# 8  1.555721  1.741279

print(df_source_train)
#           A         B
# 0  0.279545  0.107474
# 2  0.651458 -1.516999
# 6  0.833612  0.492572

print(df_source_test)
#           A         B
# 4 -1.320541  0.679631
# 8  1.555721  1.741279
```

Comment: thanx! Because of I have to use some percentile I've modified line started with rows = ...

Comment: In that case, you could use `rows = np.random.binomial(1, percentile*100, size=len(df_source))`.

Comment: Or rather, `rows = np.random.binomial(1, percentile*100, size=len(df_source)).astype('bool')`

Answer (score 15):

Below you can find my solution, which doesn't involve any extra variables.

1. Use `.sample` method to get sample of your data
2. Use `.index` method on sample, to get indexes
3. Apply `slice()`ing by index for second `dataframe`

E.g.
Let's say you have X and Y and you want to get 10 pieces sample on each. And it should be same samples, of course

```
X_sample = X.sample(10)
y_sample = y[X_sample.index]
```

Comment: Very good solution, but over-reliant on defaults ("Explicit is better than implicit"). So, I'd add explicit `replace=False` in `sample` to be sure we avoid data leak. And it will not work without explicit `loc` (`y.loc[X_sample.index, :]) though (apparently pandas default axis changed here and axis 1 is now the default:).

Comment: The method doesn't work if the index contains duplicate values, in which case `y_sample` might contain multiple rows for a single row in `X_sample`

Answer (score 3):

I like the Alexander answer but I will add an index reset before sampling. The full code:

```py
# index reset
X.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
y.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
# sampling
X_sample = X.sample(10)
y_sample = y[X_sample.index]
```

Reset of the index is used to not have problem with matching.

Answer (score 1):

I like answers from Alexander and pplonski.
Just want to add that accessing indices might need iloc as follows:

```
y_sample = y.iloc[X_sample.index]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think an even simpler solution is:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df_source_train, df_source_test, df_target_train, df_target_test = train_test_split(df_source, df_target, train_size=.6)
```